# freenas sshd port forward open failed: administratively prohibited

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, sshd, freenas

I have a freenas server with an ssh port open to the internet.
I want to access a server within the network the nas is in, so I used an ssh port forward like this: `ssh -N -L 8080:host:80 root@freenas.host`

Running that seems fine at first put when i try to use that port forward i get these messages:

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

I already checked the options `AllowTcpForwarding` and `PermitOpen` as mentioned here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58756/170512
This did not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that i used the root user.

- ssh -N -L 8080:host:80 **root**@host ~ does not work
- ssh -N -L 8080:host:80 **user**@host ~ does work

I'm not sure if that is specific to freenas, bsd or sshd in general.

Answer (score 0):

## On TrueNAS

Both my user and `root` worked for me, but this may be because I enabled port forwarding globally.

There are several settings that you may need to change across 3 different SSH configs:

```sh
grep -R AllowTcpForwarding /etc/
```

### 1. `/etc/sshd_config`

```
- # GatewayPorts no
+ GatewayPorts yes
```

### 2. `/etc/local/ssh/sshd_config`

```
- AllowTcpForwarding no
+ AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

### 3. `https://truenas.local/ui/services/ssh`

```
x Allow TCP Port Forwarding
```

### 4. Reboot!

```sh
midclt call service.restart "ssh"
```

## On macOS

For the case of macOS and SMB/CIFS, you can't connect to 445 on localhost, so you have to access it by something that's not "localhost" and not "127.0.0.1", so you have to create an entry in your hosts file:

`/etc/hosts`:

```
- 127.0.0.1   localhost
+ 127.0.0.1   localhost localnas
```

```sh
# ssh -nNT -L <local-lan>:<remote-lan> <wan-host>
ssh -nNT -L localnas:10445:127.0.0.1:445 root@truenas.local
```

Finder > Go > Connect to server

```
smb://localnas:10445
```

Note: the `10445` is arbitrary, anything over `1024` will do.

## Across the Internet

Let's say:

- you port forward `22627` (WAN) to `22` (LAN / NAS)
- you have a user `foobar` with smb and ssh access

`.ssh/config` should contain something like this:

```
Host remotenas
    Hostname truenas.example.duckdns.org
    User foobar
    Port 22627
```

And you would start the port-forward like this:

```sh
ssh -nNT -L localnas:10445:127.0.0.1:445 remotenas
```

And you would connect via Finder like this:

```
smb://foobar@localnas:10445
```